# Why is the argument for Wire.write () type-casted?

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

When I see code written for communication via I2C with external EEPROMs and RTCs and such, I always notice that when sending the register address bytes and data byte using `Write.write()`, the hexadecimal address is type-casted into a `byte` or `int` like below:

```cpp
static uint8_t read_i2c_register(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write((byte)reg);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(addr, (byte)1);
  return Wire.read();
}
```

The function is called as such

```cpp
#define ADDR 0x01
#define REG 0x20

read_i2c_register (ADDR, REG);
```

Why does the hexadecimal address of the register get type-casted in the method `Wire.write()` but not type-casted in the method `Wire.beginTransmission()`. This is utterly confusing to me since both these methods take a single byte as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `requestFrom` method is overloaded. There is a `requestFrom(int, int)`, taking two integers and a `requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t)` taking two bytes.

the above call `Wire.requestFrom(addr, 1)` does not exactly match any of them as the parameters are a `uint8_t` and an `int`. And the compiler is not allowed to favor one over the other.

So by adding the `(byte)` cast, the second argument is forced to be `uint8_t` which removes the ambiguity. That cast should be `(uint8_t)` to be fully correct in all cases.

That cast in the `write` call is not required and does nothing as `reg` is already a uint8_t (which is a byte)

Comment: Ah yes it seems my reasoning for this is correct. I was wondering why the arguments for `Wire.write()` was type-casted even though they're already of type `uint8_t`. This clears it up quite a bit. Thanks